# How to use Excel's built-in functions with numbers that contain thousand seperators

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am scanning manually through some PDF reports that contain different numbers which have usually both decimal and thousand seperators. Most of the time the comma and thousand seperators are the same as in my local setting (, = decimal, . = thousand, ; = separator of arguments). Unfortunately, Excel functions do not like to get fed with numbers that contain a thousand seperator.

## Problem

I copy values from the PDF and I don't want them to appear as copied in a cell but first manipulate them. I don't want the original number to appear in any cell. But when I do copy some values and try to feed them to a function e.g.

> =AVERAGE(1.234.456.789;3.000.000.000)

I get an errror

```
There is a problem with this formula. 
Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula
· you type: =1+1, cell shows: 2
To get around this type an apostrophe (') first:
· you type '=1+1, cell shows =1+1
```

at the moment I am forced to remove the thousand seperator manually by hand to get

> =AVERAGE(1234456789;3000000000)
> in order for the formula to work.

Is there any less laborous way to do it?

## Solution requirement

Edit: I do not want a solution like

> =AVERAGE(SUBSTITUTE("123.456.789";".";"");SUBSTITUTE("3.000.000.000";".";""))

since it is a lot more typing to do; I'd rather have a solution that either

1. includes **changing an Excel setting that stops ALL excel function from complaining about thousand separators**, or
2. as a second best solution a way to write VBA functions that make it work for each function seperately (in this case I would only require an working example for AVERAGE to be able to implement the rest on my own) like

> =MyNiceAverage(1.234.456.789;3.000.000.000)

which I am not able to do since even a VBA function will complain about parameters formated like above. I am able to implement a solution passing the arguments as a string like

> =MyNotSoNiceAverage("1.234.456.789";"3.000.000.000")

which is satisfying option either, because I am pasting huge amounts of numbers and I am reluctant to put each number in its own quotation marks.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried using find and replace ? use CTRL + H

Comment: PeterH, that is an option I've tried. But the problem is that you cannot do a CTRL + H  on an input that you are currently editing and I cannot just tell excel "do not bother" to finish the input and then do a CTRL + H on the cell because Excel prompts me to make a change to the formula or discard the edit.

Comment: You can temporarily change the separator as described here: https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/change_the_decimal_point_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html - Does that help?

Comment: Justin, no, it is not a problem of changing the seperator. As I say "the comma and thousand seperators are the same as in my local setting". It's a problem that the Excel commands do not accept numbers with the local thousand seperator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the periods in the copied values.

Like this:

```
=AVERAGE(SUBSTITUTE("123.456.789";".";"");SUBSTITUTE("3.000.000.000";".";""))
```

Comment: This is not a solution, as it requires more labour to do this each time (adding all the quotation marks etc, than to remove the seperators manually.

Comment: By saying "I don't want the original number to appear in any cell", you are tying your hands. If you are looking for least-effort that adheres to that requirement, then any text editor + find/replace is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

After you `Copy`, you can `Paste using Text Import Wizard`.

This will bring up the `Text Import Wizard` where, at `Step 3 --> Advanced` you can specify the `Decimal` and `Thousands` separators being used in the data you have copied.

This will appropriately convert the values to numbers in with your own separators.

If you don't see that item available when clicking the lower 1/2 of the `Paste` button on the `Home` tab, customize the `Quick Access Toolbar` to add it there.  You should find that command listed if you select to `Choose Commands` **from** `All Commands`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If one has office 365:

```
=AVERAGE(--SUBSTITUTE({"1.234.456.789","3.000.000.000"},".",""))
```

Otherwise you might want to enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

On the other hand, one could also just `SUM` and devide:

```
=SUM("1.234.456.789","3.000.000.000")/2
```